# Save image as Tiff

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, tiff

I'm getting a byte array from a library and I want to save it as a Tiff file grayscale / 16-bit per pixel.

I'm using this method to do so:

```
private static void CreateBitmapFromBytes(byte[] pixelValues)
{
  Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(1024, 1024, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);

  BitmapData picData = pic.LockBits
   ( new Rectangle(0, 0, pic.Width, pic.Height)
   , ImageLockMode.ReadWrite
   , pic.PixelFormat
   );
  IntPtr pixelStartAddress = picData.Scan0;

  Marshal.Copy(pixelValues, 0, pixelStartAddress, pixelValues.Length);

  pic.UnlockBits(picData);
  pic.Save("grid.tif", ImageFormat.Tiff); //< HERE IS THE ERROR
}
```

And I get the error "A generic error occurred in GDI+".
The problem occurs both on Vista/32-bit and Win7/64-bit.
I'm using .NET 4.0

**EDIT:**

If I change `ImageFormat.Tiff` to `ImageFormat.Bmp` I don't have the error. But it's still a TIFF image that I want.

Comment: At what line do you receive the error? Can you supply some pixel value bytes?

Comment: one of reasons - you dont have permission to write to directory

Comment: Bytes are... bytes. Taken 2 by 2 they're coding the grayscale on `ushort`s.

Comment: Which line you getting the error ? and how about using a free tiff lib: http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/create-16-bit-grayscale-tiff.aspx | http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/

Comment: Why not use an external lib, but isn't it supposed to work natively?

Comment: receiving same error when saving as png?

Comment: @Reniuz yes, I get the same error when saving as PNG.

Comment: try to use stream to save image. [what I found](http://forums.asp.net/t/975883.aspx/1)

Comment: Doesn't work any better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale is unsupported in GDI+.  It has nothing to do with TIFF.  This format is not yet implemented.

Comment: Oh great. Do you have a link with more information such as which other formats are not implemented (yet), when they will be, and so on?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution to solve your problem
[Solving "A generic error occurred in GDI+" exception.](http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2009/02/28/solving-quot-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-quot-exception.aspx)

Comment: this is exact article which solved problem when i had this error :)

Comment: No. It's not a permission problem.

Comment: [Understanding “A generic error occurred in GDI+.” Error](http://www.kerrywong.com/2007/11/15/understanding-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-error/) does it help ?